# Cannot Create Cash Register in Modul Accounting Odoo 16

Tags: odoo-16, odoo-accounting

So i tried to install external accounting modul from https://apps.odoo.com/apps/modules/16.0/om_account_accountant/.

But when i go to modul accounting and i tried to create Cash Register, there is no option to create or atleast button create to make Cash Register. Did u guys any have idea how to fix this problem? Thanks a lot :)

[Screen Display of Cash Register](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r7AvH.png)

Answer (score 0):

In Odoo 16 , this feature is removed. Check this module https://apps.odoo.com/apps/modules/16.0/account_statement_base/. This module add the view form to create bank/cash statement